# Какие права мне нужно поставить на папку?

Tags: php

Какие права мне нужно поставить на папку, чтобы с помощью PHP в этой директории создавать файлы?

Answer (score 2):

**[Ссылка на документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.chmod.php)**

```
// Полный доступ для владельца, доступ на чтение и выполнение для группы владельца
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0750);
```

Обратите внимание на этот ответ на **[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165183/apache-permissions-php-file-create-mkdir-fail)**.

> Если php запущен от имени того же
>   пользователя, что является владельцем
>   папки, то прав доступа 0700 должно
>   быть достаточно.

Comment: Проект уже лежит на продакшн сервере... Тоже ставить 755 права?

Comment: Зависит от того, должен быть туда доступ у простых пользователей или нет... Этого, кроме вас, никто не знает.  

Вот полная расшифровка:  
_владелец может всё, группа и все остальные могут только читать папки и заходить в них, но им запрещено записывать файлы, изменять названия файлов, удалять файлы в директориях._

Comment: У простых пользователей доступа быть не должно, только доступ у PHP скрипта для создания файлов в этой директории.

Comment: В таком случае, установите права доступа 0750

Comment: Дело в том, что веб-приложение размещено на продашн сервере и не хотелось бы ставить такие высокие права. Хватит ли прав 666 или нет? Как Вы думаете?

Comment: Зачем оставлять обычным пользователям возможность редактировать файлы (последняя 6-ка)? Зачем закрывать возможность скрипту просматривать папку (первая 6-ка)?  
Для папки, на мой взгляд, должны быть выставлены права либо 0750, либо, 0700.  
Если не уверены, подождите, пока кто-нибудь еще прокомментирует мой ответ. Я недостаточно компетентен в этом вопросе, чтобы дать вам 100% гарантию.

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое за ответ, подожду еще комментариев, может кто-то еще что-нибудь дельное напишет.

Comment: А это ниче, что php выполняется от того пользователя, под которым запущен apache/nginx, и как правило этот пользователь не входит в одну группу с "владельцем" скриптов ?